# http request c# authorization

Tags: c#, json, http-headers, httprequest

i'm currently trying to post a request over https with authorization with this code

```
const string url = "http://api.xxx.pt/";
        const string username = "username";
        const string password = "password";
        const string token = "token";
        const string json = "{jsondata}";

        try
        {
            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            WebRequest request2 = WebRequest.Create(url);

            request2.Headers["Authorization"] = token;

            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request2.Method = "POST";

            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = json;
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request2.ContentType = "application/json";

            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request2.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            // Get the request stream.
            Stream dataStream = request2.GetRequestStream();

            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close();


            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response2 = request2.GetResponse();

            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response2).StatusDescription);

            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response2.GetResponseStream();

            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);

            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response2.Close();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This program is expected to throw WebException on successful run." +
                                "\n\nException Message :" + e.Message);
            if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Status Code : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode);
                Console.WriteLine("Status Description : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

this code works fine without authentication once it's from MSDN library
once i make some changes to add some authentication

this line

```
WebResponse response2 = request2.GetResponse();
```

replies 401 - Unauthorize to access the resource

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: for the authentication to go without a problem i have this to send to the API

    GET "api url" -H "Authorization: Token token=example_token"

Comment: is this the right approch?
or webclient would be easier?

Comment: can someone give an exemple of a C# line of code for this get?

Answer (score 0):

An example of authorization header is.

Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==

I am curious to see your token value.

Comment: it's something like this
    Authorization: Basic ooshei2eeloh6eid7Ieb

Comment: can you capture your post payload using a tool like google chrome developer? please check your authorization header and see if its present in the post headers.

Comment: please try this to add authorization header theRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authToken);

Comment: thanx but it still throus an exception =/

Comment: did the authorization header get added? Is your url is diff than your site? Is service url allow CORS call?

Comment: yes it got added to my header
the url is a bit longer than my site
i dont know if it allows CORS call(i dont know what that is)!!

Comment: is it hosted under same server name? for instance if you web service url is different (means they are in difference website) than your application ur application that CORS issues might kick in. By default cross website access is not allowed unless you use jsonp

Comment: how do you generate the token? are you sure your token is valid

Comment: the token is supplied by another entitie and they say it's valid
i'm probably doing something wrong in the authentication and don't know what

Comment: if you want my opinion i would do a quick test with fiddler. use the same token in fiddler and see if you can go through. otherwise there is no way of knowing if their claim is valid or not!!!

Comment: GET "http: //api.xxx.pt/v0/entries/Authorization: Token token=myToken"
 this should do it in fiddle right?
but it still gives me this
3a
{"http_code":401,"message":"You must authenticate first."}
0

Comment: you need to do a post on the url in fiddler software. Do you have it? you cant have headers in a get request url

Comment: yes I have it but i dont use it much
i tried the GET without the header and it still replied the same thing, that i have to authenticate 1st